# What can cause Play modules to be loaded twice?

Tags: java, resources, playframework

I am trying on the [associations module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/associations-1.0.1/home), and it fails because it tries to enhance the same object twice. Debugging my test case, I discover that I have two instances of both this module and less-css module loaded! It appears that the `play.plugins` file is loaded as two resources:

- file:/C:/work/CS/portal/src/modules/associations-1.0.1/lib/play-associations.jar!/play.plugins
- jar:file:/C:/work/CS/portal/src/modules/associations-1.0.1/lib/play-associations.jar!/play.plugins

This causes the `pluginsToLoad` variable to contain two copies of this module, and everything goes haywire from here.

Is this a mis-configuration on my part? How can I investigate further / resolve?

The module only appears once in my dependencies.yml, and does not appear in application.conf

[See here for a screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Programming/play/module_loaded_twice.png).

**Update** - it seems that the classpath contains:

```
C:\work\CS\portal\src\modules\associations-1.0.1\src;
C:\work\CS\portal\src\modules\associations-1.0.1\lib\play-associations.jar;
```

And a `play.plugins` file exist both in the src folder, and in the jar. Now I need to understand why both are in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug within `play idealize`. I found these entries in the iml file:

```
<library name="Project Libraries">
  <CLASSES>
    <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/lib" />
    <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/modules/less-0.3/src" />
    <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/modules/associations-1.0.1/src" />
    <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/modules/less-0.3/lib" />
    <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/modules/associations-1.0.1/lib" />
  </CLASSES>
...
```

[I've submitted a bug](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1318-modules-loaded-twice-after-idealize-when-running-tests-via-intellij) (the workaround is to manually remove the `/src` entries)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you put the module into your
 **dependencies.yml** AND declare it as module in **application.conf**

**remove the entry in application.conf**

Comment: It is not contained in application.conf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom, play modules being loaded twice.

I discovered it was a bug in the "play war" 1.2-beta2 plugin that was causing my main jar file to be created twice with slightly different names and then both be included in the "WEB-INF/lib" dir of my war file.

I upgraded the plugin to the latest 1.2-beta4 and it seems to have been fixed